# Vertically align Links in Lists

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I've got the following HTML markup;

```
<div class="blockmenu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#!">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">item 5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I would like the links within the (blocked) LIs to appear vertically aligned like this;

[image: Vertically Aligned Link]

The link needs to be 100% of the `<li>` as whereever the user clicks they need to click that link and I don't want to use JS/jQuery to do an ONCLICK event.

My CSS so far is

```
.blockmenu ul {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}

.blockmenu li {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-position: inside;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 25%; 
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
}

.blockmenu li a { 
       height: 150px;
       margin: 10px;
       display: block;
       text-align: center;
       color: #fff;
} 

.blockmenu li:nth-child(3n-2) a {
      background: #e31937;
}
.blockmenu li:nth-child(3n-1) a {
      background: #002f5f;
}
.blockmenu li:nth-child(3n) a {
      background: #dcdcdd;
      color: #58595b;
}
```

I have created a JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/midnitesonnet/T3bWE/

Comment: your links will always span a single row? or they can fill 2 or more lines?

Comment: These ones will, but would be interested in how to make it work if they fill 2 lines or more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `line-height` in your `<a>` ***(css)*** 
To get your `link` vertical aligned, you need to set it as the same height as the `<li>`. 
 Your `<li>` `height` is `150px`. So your `line-height` should be `150px` to. 
Like in the **DEMO** and code below here.

**Css:**

```
.blockmenu li a { 
    ....
    line-height:150px;    /* The height of your li */
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T3bWE/5/)**

[More information about Line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your

```
float:left;
```

Remove it from the .blockmenu li and the list will then show vertically.

Comment: think you've misunderstood the question