# Links over two lines

Tags: html, css

I recently submitted a question '[Vertically align links in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553694/vertically-align-links-in-lists)'

However, what I'd like to try and resolve is how can I achieve the vertical alignment if the link goes into two lines - e.g.

[image: Two lines link]

There is a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/T3bWE/5/) for what has currently been achieved.

Current HTML markup is;

```
<div class="blockmenu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#!">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">item 5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And CSS is currently;

```
.blockmenu ul {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}

.blockmenu li {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-position: inside;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 25%; 
    float: left;
}

.blockmenu li a { 
       height: 150px;
       margin: 10px;
       display: block;
       text-align: center;
       color: #fff;
    line-height:150px;
} 

.blockmenu li:nth-child(3n-2) a {
      background: #e31937;
}
.blockmenu li:nth-child(3n-1) a {
      background: #002f5f;
}
.blockmenu li:nth-child(3n) a {
      background: #dcdcdd;
      color: #58595b;
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: are the menu items dynamically populated? With setting the line-height to the same height of the box you are limiting yourself... You could absolutely position the links within the boxes, but then that might not be the best solution.

Comment: `display: table-cell` could be worth a shot - see more here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting `line-height` for your anchor, you can use `display: table` on your list:

```
.blockmenu li {
    display: table;
}
```

as well as `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align:middle;` for your anchor:

```
.blockmenu li a {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T3bWE/16/)**